# Ordering and grouping MySQL data

Tags: group-by, sql-order-by

```
+----+------------------+-----------------+
| id | template_type_id | url             |
+----+------------------+-----------------+
|  1 |       1          | text            |
|  2 |       2          | text            |
|  3 |       1          | text            |
|  4 |       1          | text            |
|  5 |       1          | text            |
|  6 |       1          | text            |
|  7 |       1          | text            |
|  8 |       1          | text            |
|  9 |       2          | text            |
| 10 |       2          | text            |
+----+------------------+-----------------+
```

As i am using 1 page template and 2 page template i need to reorder above result as per 1 page and 2 page as below:

```
+----+------------------+-----------------+
| id | template_type_id | url             |
+----+------------------+-----------------+
|  1 |       1          | text            |
|  3 |       1          | text            |
|  2 |       2          | text            |
|  4 |       1          | text            |
|  5 |       1          | text            |
|  6 |       1          | text            |
|  7 |       1          | text            |
|  9 |       2          | text            |
| 10 |       2          | text            |
|  8 |       1          | text            |
+----+------------------+-----------------+
```

```
+------------------------------------------+
   ----------------  ------------------
   |               | |                 |
   |               | |                 |
   |               | |                 |
   |               | |                 |
 
   |               | |                 |
   |               | |                 |
   |               | |                 |
   |               | |                 |
   |               | |                 |
   ----------------  ------------------
+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The second example doesn't seem to be ordered at all, unless there's some other data not shown that is part of the ordering rule.

Comment: i need to group 1 page templates and 2 page templates by template_type_id as per second result. as you can consider there is publish_date already there and first result ordered by it..

Comment: You should add the publish_date data to your examples so we can understand how it affects the ordering.

Comment: @jit it really isn't clear how you want this grouped - your desired results look less ordered than your original data. Perhaps it would be worth including the options you've already attempted?

Comment: i want to display this in 2 page magazine at a time..means displaying two 1 page templates OR one 2 page template at a time. but by the order specified as in second. if you check id column from first and second result , you observed that if 1 record is 1 page template i wanna to get next 1 page record and then follow second record as it is two page template as given in result 2.

Comment: It sounds like you want to juggle the results based on some rules that are difficult to do in a set based manner (i.e. SQL) you may be better off approaching this in a procedural manner (i.e. whichever programming language you're reading the results from your database) - you would probably want to actually store the chosen layout back on the database (after all, would the following order match your rules: 1,4,2,6,3,5,8,10,9,7?

Comment: can we separate template_type_id by 1 and 2 from the result and use two 1 and one 2 page and merge the result accordingly by union...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's publish_date column in the table that is not shown and the values in it consistent with the ordering of the records in the examples 1 and 2, I suggest:

```
order by publish_date, template_type_id
```

Comment: not useful...assume publish_date is same for all.  i want to show 2 page at a time...means two 1 page or one 2 page template at a time..

Comment: So, what the is the logical ordering rule for the second table? Can you express it in plain English so that we can try to translate it into SQL?

Comment: i want to display this in 2 page magazine at a time..means displaying two 1 page templates OR one 2 page template at a time. but by the order specified as in second. if you check id column from first and second result , you observed that if 1 record is 1 page template i wanna to get next 1 page record and then follow second record as it is two page template as given in result 2.

Comment: If this is the requirement, I don't see any possibilities other than MySQL compound statements. You can open two cursors on this table, one for 1-page templates and second - for 2-page, both ordered by the publication date or id, and loop through them appropriately filling out 2-page magazine spreads.

Comment: can we do this as said above with two cursors and create an view for the result and using that view to show result 2 as i need to do pagination also...